# Mysql table structure and query

Tags: php, mysql

I think I am getting confused over something quite simple here.

I am creating a script which takes the user through a number of steps. I am just wondering if I have set up the table structure correctly and also need a little help with an insert query if possible.

My database structure is similar to this currently:

```
step_id     user_id       step_url                   step_order
   1           1       example.com?step=1              1
   2           2      test.com?step=1                  1
   3           1       example.com?step=3              2
```

Would this be the best way to do this? Or is there a better way than storing by order? E.g 
saving the next step_id in the row, or something else?

If so how would I increment the order column by 1 for each new row inserted for that user?

Also what would be the SELECT query used if user_id 1 was on step_order 1 to select the step_url for step 2.

Thanks for any help.

Paul

---

Hi Guys, thanks for your replies. I think I rushed the question a little bit because I had to be somewhere so i will try to explain a little better.

1. Each user can create as many steps as they wish and all urls will be unique
2. The users themselves will not be using the steps they are urls to direct other people to
3. On each of the steps there will be a form and after the form has been submitted and processed my script will need to direct the visitor to the next step in my users process.

   ---

Comment: I think you need to explain the requirements before we get into implementation...

Comment: Do all users go through the same steps? Could the steps ever change for new users?

Comment: How many users will be using this?  I would replace user_id with a track_id, and have a join table to match users to `tracks`, if the users will be much larger than 5 or 10.

Comment: Hi guys, I added some extra info to the bottom of the question which i think will help explain what I am trying to achieve. Thanks for taking the time to help. Paul

Answer (score 0):

Well, a better explanation of your problem would be useful.

What i've understood a better would probably be having a primary key with `AI(auto increment)` as step order and insert rows accordingly.

query answer:

```
SELECT [step_url] 
FROM [table] 
WHERE user_id = 1 
AND step_order = 2
```

::this will give you the step url for 2nd step

```
SELECT [step_url] 
FROM [table] 
WHERE user_id = 1
AND step_order = 2 
ORDER BY step_order
```

:: this will give you step url's in ascending order of steps.